# How to instantiate encapsulated object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sap-commerce-cloud

I am currently using spring. I created a restClient that uses a service based on another module. I am trying to instantiate this restClient but I always receive a null pointer exception. After investigation, it appears that the encapsulated attribute (objects) are not instantiating, their nested encapsulated neither.

This is the member variables, my class, the constructor and a method I am trying to call.

```
private OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate;
private ConsumedDestinationModel consumedDestinationModel;
@Autowired
private DestinationService<ConsumedDestinationModel> destinationService ;

public DefaultSacRestClient()
{
    consumedDestinationModel = getSacConsumedDestinationModel(getDestinationService().getAllConsumedDestinations());
    oAuth2RestTemplate = configureOAuth2Credentials(getConsumedDestinationModel());
}


@Override
public List<Story> fetchStories() {
    List<Story> stories = new ArrayList<>();

    String endpoint = getConsumedDestinationModel().getUrl() + STORIES_URL;

    stories.add(oAuth2RestTemplate.getForObject(endpoint, Story.class));
    return stories;
}
```

in my constructor, both methods getSacConsumedDestinationModel() &
configureOAuth2Credentials() returns an object.

but the method getSacConsumedDestinationModel() uses the destinationService which is not instantiated. I dont understand why the destinationService member variable is not instantiated.

Here is the application context which corresponds only to the module I am working on. This application context is appended to the global application context of the application

```
<bean id="defaultSacRestClient" class="de.hybris.platform.sacintegrationbackoffice.client.impl.DefaultSacRestClient">
    <property name="destinationService" ref="destinationService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="destinationService" class="de.hybris.platform.apiregistryservices.services.impl.DefaultDestinationService">
    <property name="destinationDao" ref="destinationDao"/>
</bean>
<bean id="destinationDao" class="de.hybris.platform.apiregistryservices.dao.impl.DefaultDestinationDao">
    <property name="flexibleSearchService" ref="defaultFlexibleSearchService"/>
    <property name="modelService" ref="defaultModelService"/>
</bean>
```

Is it a bean configuration problem? Am I missing something? There is definitely something I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems:

1. Is the class annotated with `@Component` or `@Service`?
2. Some objects are instantiated with the constructor and some aren't.

Try

```
@Service
public class DefaultSacRestClient {
    private final OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate;
    private final ConsumedDestinationModel consumedDestinationModel;
    private final DestinationService<ConsumedDestinationModel> destinationService ;

    public DefaultSacRestClient(DestinationService<ConsumedDestinationModel> destinationService) {
        this.destinationService = destinationService;
        this.consumedDestinationModel = getSacConsumedDestinationModel(destinationService.getAllConsumedDestinations());
        this.oAuth2RestTemplate = configureOAuth2Credentials(getConsumedDestinationModel());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are the bean(member variables) injected (instantiated) before the constructor is called?

Comment: If this is a bean (annotated and in your component scan), spring will instantiate and inject the destination service.